# syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ']'

Tags: php, mysql

I'm receiving the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
>   expecting ']' in C:\Program
>   Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\post.php on
>   line 13

Code:

```
<?php 
 $con=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", ""); 
 mysql_select_db("registration");
if(!$con)
{
echo "Failed to Connect to MySql".mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
echo"success";
} 
$query="INSERT INTO feed 
VALUES('$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Department]','$_POST[Event]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Phone no]')";
mysql_query($query,$con);
 ?>
```

Comment: If you input variables directly in your string you should **not** use spaces in your keys. `Phone no` is a big nono. That said, use PDO or MySQLi (`mysql_` is deprecated). Use prepared statements and bind your variables. If you don't you're open to SQL injection.

Comment: Please take a moment to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and then consider revising your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code to help with your errors. This should work. Just follow the directions.

```
<?php

//You might want to use a session for this. //
        session_start();
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "databasename");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
             echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
//Ensure the variables are the same as the ones in the database. There should be no spaces. //

        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
        $department = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['department']);
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
        $phone_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone_number']);


    $sql="INSERT INTO users SET name='$name', department = '$department', email = '$email', phone_number = '$phone_number' WHERE id='" .$_SESSION['id']."'";

        if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        header("Location: pagetobedirected.php");
        mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be this

```
      $query="INSERT INTO feed (columnName_1, columnName2, columnName_3, columnName_4, columnName_5)
    VALUES('".$_POST['Name']."','".$_POST['Department']."','".$_POST['Event']."',
'".$_POST['Email']."',
    '".$_POST['phone_no']."')"; //cant use $_post['phone no'] means you cant give space, it has
//to be phone_no.
change columnName_1 and so with your originall column name in your database
```

**Important Note:** Do not access super global directly into the query, $*POST Is superglobal, 
Use mysqli* function or PDO,

Properly escape your data before you use in the query,

Read the comment on your question, Thanks